# Ubuntu 18.04.2 cannot log in local or SSH after power failure

Tags: 18.04, server

I cannot remote into local with root, SSH is set for AD Authentication and it will not let me log in either.  Ubuntu runs in ESXi 6.5 and had a Dell Technician unplug storage array! Anyway I tried recovery mode and fsck (as vCenter had to manually run it to fix it) but states /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I went to recovery mode, then went to "root" option

on 1st Ubuntu server,
I used command `umount -l /dev/sda2` and rebooted.

On another Ubuntu server I did the same thing above but had I had to also run command `fsck -p /dev/sda2` and I also ran `fsck /dev/sda2` and rebooted.

They are now working and I can log in and SSH and all items seem to be working.